# ШабАш, шАбаш и шабашить

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Все мы знаем, что "шАбаш" - это разгул нечисти. Слово, насколько я понимаю, еврейского происхождения. Но вот интересно, почему иногда об окончании работы говорят "шабАш"? Я могу предположить, что это не имеет отношение к ведьминому шабашу, а искаженное от слова "шаббат" - "суббота", нерабочий день у иудеев. Но при этом "шабашить" - это, наоборот, подрабатывать, то есть, значение прямо противоположное слову "шабАш".
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этими словами.

Answer (score 3):

Слово шабаш - "самовольное прекращение работы",происходит от древнееврейского шабат, "день отдыха,покоя"***(то есть «суббота, день отдыха, день молитвы, посвящённый Богу, день, когда запрещены обычные будничные дела.- прим.- мое).*** См. Шанский Н.М. Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов/ Н.М. Шанский, Т.А. Боброва. — 7-е изд., стереотип. — М.: Дрофа, 2004). Я познаю мир.Русский язык. Дет.энцикл./С.В. Волков. М.: ООО" Издательство АСТ": ООО "Издательство Апрель", 2002.-493с.
А появление негативного оттенка у этого слова связано с народными поверьями. Относительно того как слово " шабаш" получило свое негативно-мистическое значение, существуют несколько версий. 
Согласно одной, ***шабаш (sabbat) - еврейское слово обозначающее седьмой день недели.***Танцы крестьян часто проходили в суб­ботнюю ночь, чтобы можно было отдохнуть в официально разрешенный воскресный праздник, а по ночам - потому что это бы­ло единственное свободное время. Во время праздника люди благодарили своих богов, просили плодородия и приносили им пожертвования.
         Христианская религия пречислила всех древних языческих богов к слугам дьявола, а людей поклонявшихся своим богам - к ведьмам и колдунам. Для того, чтобы не быть осудженными, люди уходили праздновать старинные праздники в укромные места. Во всех мифологиях ведуны, ведьмы, чародеи, шаманы и т. д., покровительствуемые всемогущими духами, особенно отличались волшебной властью над атмосферными явлениями. Поэтому самые ранние представления о ведовских сборищах указывают на ночные полеты ведьм по воздуху для вызывания гроз и ливней, для скрадывания солнца, луны, звезд и т. п.
 По другой версии подобные представления не имели ничего общего ни с древними языческими праздниками, ни с трактовкой их христианским богословием или мифологией. Истоки подобного значения, сформировавшегося уже к середине XIV века, то есть ещё до начала полномасштабной «охоты на ведьм», предлагается искать в целенаправленном и организованном властями антисемитизме. В XIV веке в Европе появились слухи о том, что эпидемии различных болезней и голод вызваны злонамеренными действиями евреев, которые отравляют колодцы, подбрасывают в города и селения яды, отравляющие снадобья и тому подобное. Постепенно в народном сознании евреи трансформировались в демонические силы, в том числе и в ведьм, а их «зловещие сборища» в шаббат заменились дьявольские шабашами, на которых приспешники сатаны докладывают ему о злых делах против людей и церкви. Согласно Викепедии: Ересь и формальный культ дьявола стали синонимами. Еретики составляли «синагогу» дьявола, устраивая в честь его периодические субботы (шаббат → шабаш). Участниками этих суббот являлись уже не жалкие ведьмы, а представители всех классов и рангов — князья светские и духовные, монахи, священники и т. д.

Со словом  "шабашить"  проще. Поскольку шабат у Евреев считался выходным днем, работа в эти дни дни считалось дополнительном заработком. Т.е. шабашили - подрабатывали дополнительно, в выходные дни. А "шабашник", как пишет Марина Королева, - это тот, кто работал в бригаде по найму, обычно на сезонных работах.

Comment: Когда по окончании рабочего дня говорят: всё ШАБАШ!, - то тут налицо связь с субботой евреев как днём отдыха. Т.е. в этой фразе ШАБАШ=ОТДЫХ.

Comment: следопыт, вы правы: именно в этом значении сперва было заимствовано это слово, с ударением на последнем слоге. Это, считает Историко-этимологический словарь Черных, русское новообразование.